# ActivityIndicator not showing

Tags: ios, activity-indicator

I'm implementing what seems to be standard code for iOS activity indicator, but it's not showing. This is what I do, following advice from around here:

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
indicator.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80.0, 80.0);
indicator.hidden = NO;
indicator.center = self.view.center;
[self.view insertSubview:indicator atIndex:100]; // to be on the safe side
[indicator bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = TRUE;
```

Then in `viewWillAppear`, just before calling my long process method:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

My threadStartsAnimating:

```
-(void)threadStartAnimating:(id)data
{
    [indicator startAnimating];
}
```

Then I have a Parse.com method that does some work in the background:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {       
    if(!error) {
        // do some work
        [indicator stopAnimating];
    }
}
```

For all I can see, this should work. But it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: `UIKit` should only be called from the main thread

Comment: Only update UI on main thread

Comment: `[indicator bringSubviewToFront:self.view];` You probably meant `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:indicator];`

Comment: Thanks, @Jkmn, I changed it but still no luck. I put in a couple of indicator.isAnimating logs and it's animating once I start it, going for 5-7 seconds during the database fetch, and stopping after. But on the screen - nada.

Comment: I guess I should add that I'm on xCode 5, running the app on iPhone 4S with the latest OS7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to manipulate your view (i.e. addSubview, etc) it is best to do so in viewWillAppear. viewDidLoad is too early to manipulate views since other methods will still alter it (i.e. setFrame).

So moving your current code from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The `startAnimating` should be called on the main thread and not in a new thread.
So just call `[indicator startAnimating];` in the `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Still no indicator showing up. I even tried commenting out the [indicator stopAnimating] but nothing doing. Is my indicator declared correctly?

Comment: Can you post the declaration of `indicator`, also with a breakpoint and make sure that the `indicator` is not `nil`.

Comment: The declaration is in my question. I did an NSLog and the indicator is not nil.